# How do I find out what web sites link to mine?

Tags: search-engines, links

Is there a way of using something like as a search engine to find out which web sites out there link to mine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In google type: `link:yoursite.com`

Also their [webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) will give you a better rundown.  Bing also has webmaster tools.

Comment: The webmaster tools are definitely the winners here. The `link:` syntax gives incomplete results.

Comment: You're better off trying this in Yahoo, not Google. You get redirected to http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com which is pretty good.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anymore

Answer (score 2):

It's pay-for-play, but [SEOmoz](http://www.seomoz.org/tools) recently released their "Open Site Explorer" tool which analyzes backlinks, (amongst other things) as well.

Comment: You can see the top 25 backlinks for free!

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.yahoo.com/search/siteexplorer/ is much better than using "link:yoursite.com" in Google search.

The 1st one will give you a much wider list of links to your site. Google "link:yoursite.com" used to give you many results too, but after they did some changes on it and now is returning nothing compared to what site explorer returns.

Unfortunately Microsoft took over Yahoo and there seem to be plans to turn siteexplorer off soon: ["The Yahoo! Site Explorer team is planning tighter integration between Site Explorer and Bing Webmaster..."](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2010/08/api_updates_and_changes.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can install google analytics on your page and see "some" backlinks there, by seeing url's that have sent customers to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Try [www.backlinkwatch.com](http://www.backlinkwatch.com) it mines the search engines for backlinks to you and shows you the results with pagerank values attached.